# Motivation and proof of Newton's 3rd law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws

I have a doubt regarding the motivation for Newton's 3rd law. Is it based on experimental evidence from collision results (where the velocities seem to redistribute based on masses and the net momentum of the system is conserved) or is it an empirical law which in turn proves the conservation of momentum theorem when it comes to collisions (1d).
I tried to find the explanation behind that thought process but I was not able to find any.

Comment: No theoretical prove within classical mechanics. As a principle of the theory, it's formulated as one of the most basic law that agrees with experimental measurements, and theory starts from it taken it as true (true means that agrees with reality)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Newton's Third Law actually work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/348514/)